# How to list child categories in custom category template?

Tags: categories, customization

I'm trying to create a custom category template that will display a list of the current category's child categories. Besides the name and link to the category I also want to add a thumbnail and the category description.
I tried the following code but it didn't return anything:

```
<?php 

$catid = get_category(get_query_var( 'cat' ));

$termchildren = get_term_children( $catid, 'category' );

echo '<ul>';

foreach( $termchildren as $cat ) {

$term = get_term_by( 'id', '$cat', 'category' );

echo '<li>'.$term->name.'</li>';

}

?>
```

I've left out the other parts of the html list at this stage as I'm just trying to get it to work and will add them in later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This piece of code will return you the child categories of a parent-

```
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
$child_categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat_id )
);
```

Just pass the category id to `$cat_id` variable which children you want. After that you can design or print those as you want. Example-

```
foreach ( $child_categories as $child ) {
    // Here I'm showing as a list...
    echo '<li>'.$child ->cat_name.'</li>';
}
```

Hope this is gonna help.

Comment: You welcome :) @jrcollins